# rails custom validator - add to errors in model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, validation

I see custom validators being used in models (good) but I also see the validators themselves adding to the record errors object.
e.g. I see
(changed example)

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
   # implement the method called during validation
   def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
     record.errors[attribute] << 'must be Mr / Mrs / Dr.' unless ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Dr.'].include?(value)
   end
end
```

This feels a bit like a state thing that should be being done in the controller and the validation should just return `true`/`false` but maybe not.

Comment: If you have a `has_many` relation that you want to limit to just one, why don't you use `has_one` instead?

Comment: I believe this was code copied from another question @Michael was answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169589/rails-3-1-limit-the-number-of-child-models

Comment: completely changed the example :)

Comment: I think your new example is even more confusing - it this question about adding error messages in model vs. custom validation OR custom validation vs. controller?

Comment: sorry, it's about custom validators in ActiveRecord (excuse that typo, fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend towards this pattern:

```
errors.add[:name] << :invalid_honorific
```

Where the error set by the model is a symbol (acting more like an error code), which is then handled by the view layer, `.yml` files of whatever. This avoids putting too much presentation layer stuff in the model.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a case by case thing. In general the messaging on validation really doesn't happen in the controller at all. When you use a canned validator you can specify the message differently by manipulating the .yml files and to do so you adjust things and add values under the model, not the controller.

In fact I would suggest always putting the messages that are custom into the locales .yml files

I can see an argument for putting more general failure messages in the controller.